# How to fix Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: angular, iframe, x-frame-options

I'm getting error while using i-frame in angular

Refused to display 'https://localhost:2800/sample/id' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this error

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Solution as i have access to server site. i disable X-frame-options in dev profile and it worked.

Alternative Solution :
you can also change X-frame-option in response headers to sameOrigin or allow-from uri(obsolete You can See [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)).

I hope It helps Someone. Thank You